# QUdpSocket bind failed

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I'm having an issue with QT Udp sockets. 
Assuming all headers are correctly included, I'm writing:

```
QUdpSocket* s = new QUdpSocket();
bool ok = s->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 8081);
if(!ok)
{
    std::cout << "Cannot bind socket: " << s->errorString().toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

The output is always
**Cannot bind socket: operation is not supported**

I made several attempts to solve this: tried disabling firewall, tried to bind specifing only the port, searching in internet, but the problem still remain.

My architecture is AMD64, Windows 7 installed

Comment: Check if the port 8081 is not already in use or if it's working with another port.

Comment: I tried using different ports, even if the error message in this case should be "Address already in use". Also with other ports the problem remains, it seems to be an OS-related issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a platform specific issue, since a UnsupportedSocketOperationError is thrown.

```
/* 10 */ 
\value UnsupportedSocketOperationError The requested socket operation is
       not supported by the local operating system (e.g., lack of
       IPv6 support).
```

I solved by adding:

```
s->setProxy(QNetworkProxy::NoProxy);
```

before calling s->bind().

Comment: This helped me with a similar problem involving QTcpSocket.